# How do I hook into new connections to ErlyVideo to run my own Erlang Authentication code?

Tags: authentication, erlang

I'm working on a video conferencing app.

We have a server running erlyVideo for internal video streaming.
We have a rest service on our web server for our erlyVideo server to call to validate session keys from our external site.

What we're stuck on is how to hook into new connections to pass the session key to the REST service to decide whether or not to terminate the connection.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using authentication described in their docs?
http://erlyvideo.org/authorization

Comment: I have trouble following Max's English in the documentation. I was hoping for a specific "put the name of the erlang module at the top of something.config" type of thing. I guess I'll take another look at what Max wrote.

Comment: btw. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: lol. There is a russian version of this document, with more examples: [original article](http://dev.erlyvideo.org/projects/erlyvideo/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), [google translate version](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.erlyvideo.org%2Fprojects%2Ferlyvideo%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B2%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B7%25D0%25B0%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use apps_rewrite_play module:

{rtmp_handlers, [...., {apps_rewrite_play, "http://rest-service"},...]},